# Leaflet - Projection

Tags: javascript

[Drupals Leaflet](https://www.drupal.org/project/leaflet) uses the Mercantor projection for leaflet, I would like to have a polar-projection. Is this possible? Any ideas of how to make this possible becuase I dont seem to find anything

Thanks!

Comment: Have you researched if http://leafletjs.com/ allows this at all?

Comment: This seem to do it https://github.com/kartena/Proj4Leaflet but is it good(safe) to use for Drupal7

Comment: Drupal module is only a wrapper around leafletjs library, so why not? Everything that works with this library should be pretty OK. As usual - there is only one way to tell for sure: try. And if you will find it working, file an issue requesting this as an option in module.